# Can you change a line after you've outputted it with System.out.println?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, debugging

I have been coding for a while now and as far as I'm aware, once you've outputted a line to System.out.println in Java; you cannot change it.

The reason I ask this question is because of some very strange results from my program. The program records the time of the bubble sort and merge sort algorithms in sorting different kinds of int arrays and prints the average of these times at different sizes of n, where n is the size of the array.

Now I've had a litany of problems with this program thus far, but I do not understand how the following is possible:

```
...
At 200000, randomly-sorted takes: 
NaN                  //Expected output, since I did not activate the random arrays.
...
```

However, ***at the same line***, and in an unpredictable manner, the program occasionally does this:

```
...
At 200000, randomly-sorted takes: 
75683.45
...
```

And then swaps back again after a while!

So the program is somehow managing to **replace** the outputted line, which I have never experienced before.

Any help or clarification very much appreciated! If you need the code, I am more than happy to share.

EDIT: To clarify, this is on a Macbook Air running Java SE 6. As for the code, please refer to my Github account with the entire project at the following link - https://github.com/danielsoutar/complexityPractical.

Side-note: One other thing. For bubble sort, the randomly-generated arrays apparently take longer to sort than a reverse-sorted array, which is clearly nonsense. Not sure if that matters to this problem but it is something to note.

Comment: Is something in your code writing carriage returns (`\r`)?

Comment: The only thing in my code that does anything like that is once - "System.out.println("\n");", which is every time I test a sorted array, reverse-sorted array, etc

Comment: I always believe system is always correct. I see program behaves with Randomness. it must to be something to do with the memory or that data-set.

Comment: @Dinesh not always... combination of System.err.println and System.out.println delivers weird output sometimes!

Comment: Each array uses randomly-generated numbers. In the case of a randomly-sorted array, that array is then returned directly. A sorted array in this program is one where the random numbers are then 'pre-sorted' and then thrown to the sorting algorithm.

Comment: If you are using Windows, then look for all the places in the code where you use `\n` (either printing or reading), and use `System.lineSeparator()` instead.

Comment: This is on a Macbook air running Java SE 6.

Comment: Murat could you clarify what you mean by 'snippet'?

Comment: The relevant code, so we can reproduce it :)

Comment: At any point, are you reading a file or getting a file from the internet in that program? You really should post the code, preferably slimmed down to a [mcve].

Comment: No, I am not. The complete project is now attached in a link to my Github profile.

Comment: No offense, but this looks like the following is happening: The first line appears several times in a huge chunk of output, maybe accumulated from multiple runs (depends on how/where you collect output), and you mistakenly think they're the same.

Comment: Not at all, that's exactly what I thought as well - I assure you that is not the case. The outputted line is meant to occur once for each kind of array at each size.

Comment: Are you aware that your application is running virtually forever? I started it 5 minutes ago and it still spits out data once in a while...

Comment: Yes. That is probably because the program is attempting to sort seven different kinds of arrays of integers that span up to a million elements!

Comment: Let's just say I prefer more data over less data.

Answer (score 0):

the question was kinda unclear to me, but as far as I understand you could take a look at RegEx for filtering out on a String or clear the Console and put your output back in.

Clear console:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

RegEx example:

```
yourString.replaceAll("[yourCharactersToReplace]","");
```

Comment: Please refer to the project at the link attached. Simply run the program and you should find that the random lines change unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` refers to a `PrintStream` instance.  In the abstract, a `PrintStream` object represents a place where you can send text.  Period.   Once the text is sent, that's the end of the story.

But in reality the text actually goes *somewhere*.  If you are invoking your Java program from a command line, then it's very likely that the place where the text goes is a *terminal emulator* window or a *console* window; and it's also very likely that the console recognizes certain codes that your program can embed in the text that tell it to do things.

Things like, change the color of the text, move the cursor around in the window, and over-write text that already was there.

There have been literally *hundreds* of different coding systems to let a computer program do those things on a terminal screen/window, but one is supported by almost all consoles and terminal emulators.  Google for "ANSI escape codes" to learn more about it.

If you want your program to purposefully move the cursor around, change the text color, etc.  Then you might want to use a 3rd party library like jcurses (google for that too) to handle the possibility of a console that does not accept (or is not configured to accept) ANSI escape codes.

Comment: Whilst that makes sense, unfortunately that does not answer the question: how can my program randomly replace my outputted lines when no apparent command is given to do so?

Comment: If your program outputs the right codes, either on purpose or by accident, then it can move the console or terminal cursor so that the next thing the program outputs will overwrite something that it had previously output.  A simple \r character embedded in the output (see Andy Turner's comment on your question) often will return the cursor to the beginning of the current line.

Comment: That makes sense, but I have not used the carriage return in my code, which is why I'm so confused!

Comment: @DanielSoutar Escape sequences won't have any effect on output that is re-directed to a file.  If you run your program, redirecting the output to a file, then open the file in a text editor, you will see exactly what the program wrote, in the order that it was written.